# Is software fuzzing safe?

Tags: fuzzing

Is software fuzzing safe (Anerican fuzzy lop or AFL for example)? What's its probability of producing a random input that can make the program

- Delete a file or
- Connect to a random server

into a program?

Comment: Figuring that out is the whole point of fuzzing. Fuzzing tests if the software behaves unexpectely.

Comment: @schroeder I understand that but can it give a program a dangerous input that could delete a file? What's the probability of random input? What if I'm fuzzing a browser and it starts connecting to loads of machines by accident?

Comment: Let me explain: if the program has the function to do something, fuzzling can potentially trigger that functionality.

Comment: @schoroeder Could you give a probability please? Does it take days to make something like that on average to happen? 1% or 2%? Or does it depend on input perhaps?

Comment: @mike1024: The probability is between 0 and 100%. The specific value depends __FULLY__ on the specific program and the way you fuzz it. Just make sure that there is nothing to harm in the environment you fuzz if you don't want harmful things to happen accidentally.

Comment: @Steffen Ullrich Thank you very much. So programs like interpreters are quite safe to fuzz, despite having networking and file I/O functions?

Comment: @mike1024: I have no idea how you come to this conclusion. I did not say anything like this and I would also not agree to this. Like I said, it depends fully on the specific program __and the way you fuzz it__. You narrowed down the program a little bit (but really only a little) but not specify at all how do you fuzz it.

Comment: An interpreter is probably the _worst_ thing you can fuzz if you don't do it safely.

Comment: @forest Could fuzzing likely cause the program to connect to another server?

Comment: @mike1024 Unless it already has routines for connecting to a server, then it's very unlikely. Opening a network connection requires a number of very specific syscalls to be called with the right arguments in the right order, which is only likely if there exist functions to do that. Even if it did connect to another server though, it's not like it would _do_ anything (again, assuming the program is not designed for networking in general).

Comment: @forest Thank you. So running a fuzzer for an hour is fine and won't really cause any danger.

Comment: @mike1024 Again it really depends on the exact program. Only way to know is to fuzz it. ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no way to give you a probability for *every* program, but I can say that **no** it is not safe to run a fuzzer on a program with access to a filesystem that you do not want damaged. While programs that do not do any I/O at all are much less likely to delete or modify files, it is still absolutely possible. I have had data on filesystems damaged (and in one case, the filesystem itself got corrupted) as a result of fuzzing with AFL. Thankfully in my case, the program only had access to an empty partition...

Comment: Thank you. So VMs are recommended for the job I guess..

Comment: Just use a virtual machine and you should be fine. That's what I usually do